# iOS: Hide MapView But keep Overlay Image?

Tags: ios

I am working on an application where I need to overlay an image map over mapkit. So instead of displaying the mapkit's map, I display my image map. Hence I only need the mapkit's coordinate stuff but not the map itself.

I did this by adding my image map as an overly over the mapkit's map.

Now, the problem is that when the app loads, it renders the map-kit's map first, then overlays my image map. I tried to minimize my map's size to provide a seamless experience but still.

I wonder if I can either:

1- Delay the appearance of the map-kit's map until the overlay image is loaded.

2- or set the map-kit's map to alpha=0 while keeping its overlay images.

Any other solution is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I can just sent the background of the mapview to transperent

view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0];